# Updating Data on a OneNote Page Error, "Timeouts are not supported on this stream"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-onenote

I have the goal of being able to programmatically update OneNote page data using C#. The [Microsoft Graph API reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) suggests this can only be done by page element, not by page, and gives the following C# Graph SDK example:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"[
   {
    'target':'#para-id',
    'action':'insert',
    'position':'before',
    'content':'<img src=""image-url-or-part-name"" alt=""image-alt-text"" />'
  }, 
  {
    'target':'#list-id',
    'action':'append',
    'content':'<li>new-page-content</li>'
  }
]
"));

var pages = new OnenotePage();
pages.Content = stream;

await graphClient.Me.Onenote.Pages["{onenotePage-id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(pages);
```

Below is the relevant snippet of my code:

```
GraphServiceClient client; // authenticated service client
CancellationToken cancellationToken; // a cancellation token
string userId; // identifier of user whose page contains the paragraph to be updated
string pageId; // identifier of page containing paragraph to be updated
string paragraphId; // identifier of paragraph to be updated
string filePath; // location of text file containing updated paragraph data

await client.Users[userId].Onenote.Pages[pageId]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(new OnenotePage
    {
        Content = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            // [
            //    {
            //       'target':'{paragraphId}',
            //       'action':'replace',
            //       'content':'<p>{File.ReadAllText(filePath)}</p>'
            //    }
            // ] 
            $"[{{'target':'{paragraphId}','action':'replace','content':'<p>{File.ReadAllText(filePath)}</p>'}}]"))
    }, cancellationToken);
```

Microsoft's REST documentation includes `PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/onenote/pages/{id}/content` as a valid HTTP request, so my above code seems like it should work, even though it doesn't use the `.Me` option as in their example. For some reason, however, my code keeps throwing an `InvalidOperationException`, declaring that, `"Timeouts are not supported on this stream,"` whenever it tries to execute the `await` command. Below are the details of the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
    HResult=0x80131509
    Message=Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
    Source=System.Private.CoreLib
    StackTrace:
     at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
```

When I try to run the raw REST command [on the official Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I get a `No Content - 204` message, confirming that the PATCH worked. Please note again, however, that I am instead simply [using the C# MS Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1011).

Where am I going wrong? How can I accomplish my goal?

**EDIT:** I still don't have a solution to the SDK throwing `InvalidOperationException`s at me, and thus do not consider this  matter resolved, but since the API seems to be working just fine, I went ahead and found a workaround to accomplish my goal. Posted here, in case anyone else encounters my same issue and needs something that works.

```
GraphServiceClient client; // authenticated service client
CancellationToken cancellationToken; // a cancellation token
string userId; // identifier of user whose page contains the paragraph to be updated
string pageId; // identifier of page containing paragraph to be updated
string paragraphId; // identifier of paragraph to be updated
string filePath; // location of text file containing updated paragraph data

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Patch,
    client.Users[userId].Onenote.Pages[pageId].Content
        .Request()
        .RequestUrl)
{
    Content = new StringContent(
        // [
        //    {
        //       'target':'{paragraphId}',
        //       'action':'replace',
        //       'content':'<p>{File.ReadAllText(filePath)}</p>'
        //    }
        // ]
        $"[{{'target':'{paragraphId}','action':'replace','content':'<p>{File.ReadAllText(filePath)}</p>'}}]",
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json")
};

await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(request);
await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: (1) Share the detailed error code with requestid, timestamp (2) Outside of the above code, can you repro the same with Graph Explorer/POSTMAN too with same payload?

Comment: I have updated my post to include as much of the requested information as I am able.

Comment: ok, here is the catch. If its the Graph error, then you will be receiving the graph error code, along with requestid, timestamp for it. Unfortunately the above error you're pointing is related to Windows error code (look at the hex code value); thats the reason when you tried with Graph explorer the PATCH call worked. Glad that we isolated the issue out of graph, so now you concentrate why you receive the Windows error from your API call.

Comment: @Dev This error is produced by the [official C# Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).  So it isn't simply a windows error.

Comment: Thanks @BrentArias then the issue lies with Graph SDK, not with API. Glad to see that you filed the issue in the repro. Lets wait for the update in that...

Comment: I have found a workaround, but do not consider the matter closed. I would still very much like a solution that more fully utilizes the SDK, rather than resorting to making a direct REST invocation. My post has been edited to reflect said workaround.